# Need to check user click print button or cancel button in print in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

i need to check if user click print button or not in window.print.  I tried afterprint but it shows my console message for both print and cancel buttons.  How to check if user only click print button

```
this is jquery code

 <button class="btn btn-danger print not_print" >Print invoice</button>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

$('.print').click(function(){  

window.print();

});


  window.addEventListener('afterprint', (event) => {
  console.log('After print');
  });

 });

</script>
```

Comment: How is the logic bound to your cancel button?

Comment: i only need to check print